# How to perform a Apache Drill date range query?

Tags: apache-drill

As the question puts, how do I make a date range query with Apache Drill? I see my "date" columns in my csv file are shown using the following format "2016-01-9 08:00:00.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testdate.csv:

```
2016-01-9 08:00:00.0,dev1
2016-02-9 08:00:00.0,dev2
2016-03-9 08:00:00.0,dev3
2016-04-9 08:00:00.0,dev4
2016-05-9 08:00:00.0,dev5
```

Query:

```
select columns[0],columns[1] from dfs.`/home/impadmin/testdate.csv` 
     where columns[0]  BETWEEN '2016-02-9 08:00:00.0' AND '2016-04-9 08:00:00.0';
```

output:

```
+-----------------------+---------+
|        EXPR$0         | EXPR$1  |
+-----------------------+---------+
| 2016-02-9 08:00:00.0  | dev2    |
| 2016-03-9 08:00:00.0  | dev3    |
| 2016-04-9 08:00:00.0  | dev4    |
+-----------------------+---------+
```